# View content of all files modified on certain date

Tags: bash, grep, cat, ls, piping

I would like to print out the content of files in one directory. I want to see only the content of files that have been modified today. I tried this approach:

```
ls -lt | grep '6. Dez' | cat
```

Since it does not work, I am wondering what would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Don't parse `ls`.  Use `find`.  See `man find`, search for `-mtime`.

Comment: why is `ls` parsing bad?

Comment: Aside from other problems, consider a file named `6. Dez` that was probably created an year back.  Your approach would find it, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get files modified within last day, you can use:

```
find . -mtime -1
```

Then you can print them all with

```
find . -mtime -1 -exec cat {} \;
```